# jQuery on click method not being called on array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am printing out an array of products to the screen. There is a delete button being printed along with each product. The code is as follows:-

```
const output = document.getElementById('output');

function delete_item(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log("ID " + id);
}

let productsArray = [];

$.getJSON('/products', products => {
    let outputContent = '';

    productsArray = Object.values(products);

    productsArray.forEach(product => {  
        outputContent += `<div data-id="${ product.ID }">
                          <div id='edit'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>
                          <div id='delete'><i class='fa fa-trash-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>
                          <div id='product'> <span class='name'> <a href=''>${product.NAME}</a></span>
                          <span class='price'>Price: £${product.PRICE}</span>
                          </div>`;

    });

    $('#delete').click(function(){
        delete_item();
    });

    output.innerHTML = outputContent;
});
```

Currently, I would just like the delete_item function to print out the correct product id. However, the function is never invoked.

Is my `.click()` function within the scope of delete div, and why is the `click()` function not being called when clicking the delete div?

Comment: You also should create html dom elements _before_ attach events to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.*** First of all same `id` for multiple element will not work when it come to `jQuery`, so convert `id` to `class` like below:-

```
<div class='delete'>
```

***2.*** Use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):-

```
$(document).on('click','.delete',function(){
  delete_item($(this).parent().attr('data-id')); // pass data-id to function
});
```

***3.*** Change function like below:-

```
function delete_item(id){
    console.log("ID " + id);
}
```

***4.*** Put `delete function` outside of `$.getJSON()`.

***So the full code is now like this:-***

```
const output = document.getElementById('output');

function delete_item(id){ //change in function
    console.log("ID " + id);
}

let productsArray = [];

$.getJSON('/products', products => {
    let outputContent = '';

    productsArray = Object.values(products);

    productsArray.forEach(product => {  
    outputContent += `<div data-id="${ product.ID }">
                        <div id='edit'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>
                        <div class='delete'><i class='fa fa-trash-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>
                        <div id='product'> <span class='name'> <a href=''>${product.NAME}</a></span>
                        <span class='price'>Price: £${product.PRICE}</span>
                        </div>`;

    }); // changed id to class
    output.innerHTML = outputContent;
});

$(document).on('click','.delete',function(){ // put click functionality outside
  delete_item($(this).parent().attr('data-id')); // pass data-id to function
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're adding multiple elements with the same id. The id  should be unique in the document. Instead, use a class:

```
productsArray.forEach(product => {  
    outputContent += `  <div data-id="${ product.ID }">
                        <div class='edit'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>
                        <div class='delete'><i class='fa fa-trash-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>
                        <div class='product'> <span class='name'> <a href=''>${product.NAME}</a></span>
                        <span class='price'>Price: £${product.PRICE}</span>
                        </div>`;

});

$('.delete').click(function(){
    delete_item($(this).parent().data("id"));
});
```

This will send the id to the function:

```
function delete_item(id){
    console.log("ID " + id);
}
```

Comment: You didn't handle `$(this).attr('data-id')` inside `delete_item()` yet ...

Comment: Thanks, added that!

Answer (score 1):

You have more problems in your concept. The first is the duplicate ID usage and than the click event binding - you should register events to body element to register the event also to newly added elements. Here is a working code:

```
const output = document.getElementById('output');

function delete_item(id){
  console.log("ID " + id);
}

let productsArray = [];

$.getJSON('/products', products => {
  let outputContent = '';

  productsArray = Object.values(products);

  productsArray.forEach(product => {  
    outputContent += `  <div data-id="${ product.ID }">
                        <div class='edit'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>
                        <div class='delete'><i class='fa fa-trash-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>
                        <div class='product'> <span class='name'> <a href=''>${product.NAME}</a></span>
                        <span class='price'>Price: £${product.PRICE}</span>
                        </div>`;

});

$('body').on('click', '.delete', function(){
    delete_item($(this).parent().attr('data-id'));
});

output.innerHTML = outputContent;
});
```